# Does anyone know the term for this mobile "grabber" section?

Tags: mobile

Does anyone know the term for mobile sections that can be collapsed/expanded using a grabber? In the image below this is the section with the white background.

[image: What is the name of the white moveable section?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this a called a sheet in iOS.

A more specific version is the share sheet.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/presentation/sheets

Answer (score 2):

They are called "Pull Up" controllers, they part of sheets and follows same design specification but sheets popups automatically in response to certain user actions while Pull ups are user initiated.

[image]